# How can I add multiple email addresses in Outlook field "To" via C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-object-model

Anybody know how can I add multiple email addresses in Outlook field "To" via C#?

```
foreach (var to in mailTo)
            newMail.To += to + "; ";
```

When I try do it how I described this above I receive next kind of string:
mail1@mail.commail2@mail.commail3@mail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`+=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew(v=VS.80).aspx) operator doesn't work how you are trying to use it.

```
a += b + c;
```

has no meaning. If you want to do it this way you'll have to add brackets around the right hand side:

```
newMail.To += (to + "; ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
```